# Bootstrap accordion add active class for specific panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How add active class on opened panel ? I open panel by hash.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var id = window.location.hash;
            $(id).trigger('click');
            $("#accordion").find('id').addClass("in");
        });
        }
```

But now i need add active class on .panel-header . With click i did this

```
 $('.panel-heading a').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.panel-header').addClass('active');
});
```

How add active class without user click ? On .panel-header 
to opened panel?

Here code with html [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32582/)

Comment: Can you add the html code you are using?

Comment: Sure - [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/iWuZh7zf)

Comment: great. Now make that smaller (remove everything that is not necessary, replace large amounts of text or html with stuff like "tab 1", "tab 2" etc.) and edit it into your post.

Comment: I add my code to [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32582/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var id = window.location.hash,
    elem = $("#accordion").find('id');
  $(id).trigger('click');
  elem.addClass("in");
  elem.parent().find('.panel-header').addClass('active');
});
```